# Change an arduino variable in for loop from C#

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

I am having a project which is control a stepper motor by *Arduino* with `C#` GUI and I have no idea how to change the `n` variable of my for loop from a textbox in `C#`. For example, I would type a value of `n` whenever I want to change the angle of a stepper motor.

Here is my *Arduino* code:

```
int i;
int n;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    delay(10);
}

int received = 0;
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() == 1) {
        received = Serial.read();
        switch (received) {
           case 50:     // Received ASCII 0
              digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
              break;   //Move on
           case 51:     // Received ASCII 1
              digitalWrite(2, LOW);
              for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
                 delayMicroseconds(300);
                 digitalWrite(10, LOW);
                 delayMicroseconds(600);
                 digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                 delayMicroseconds(300);
              }
              delay(1000);
              break;   //Move on
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace Serial_send {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1() {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
       foreach (string port in ports) {
           cbPORT.Items.Add(port);
       }
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       string n =  tbgoc.Text.ToString();
       string t = cbPORT.Text.ToString();
       string s = tbDATA.Text.ToString();
       serial(t, s);
   }

   void serial(string Port_name, string data_send) {
       SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(Port_name, 9600);
       sp.Open();
       sp.Write(data_send);
       sp.Close();
   }
} //end form
} //end namespace
```

Thank u for your time to provide any help and sorry for my bad english.

regards

Comment: You care capturing your value in n, but then you aren't passing it to anything, so it's not being used.

Comment: Thank you, i am a newbie to this :(. Do you have any idea about how to do a for loop in arduino that i can change "n" in my C# GUI?

Comment: Well, now you are sending 0 or 1 and changing the value of a pin. Do you still need this or you just want to set the angle according to the variable? And how big is that? Anyway most of the code is already written, so it should be trivial if you actually wrote it

Comment: I download this code from a tutorial in youtube. I still need send 0 or 1 to arduino to control on/off stepper motor. and i want n is between 1-400 to get my stepper rotate 2 round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define an appropriate command convention to control your board. In order to keep it simple, I would suggest you always send the value of `n` adopting the following convention:

- `n=0`: turn the power off
- `n>0`: turn the power on and use the value of `n` to do your stuff

In addition, instead of parsing the received data in Arduino char by char, use the [`Serial.parseInt`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) function that is more robust.

> `parseInt()` returns the first valid (long) integer number from the serial buffer. Characters that are not integers (or the minus sign) are skipped.

Here is the modified loop function in the Arduino code:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() == 1) {

        //Read first int until the comma
        received = Serial.parseInt();

        if (received == 0) { //Power off
            digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
        } else { //Power on and set n
            n = received;
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
            for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
                delayMicroseconds(300);
                digitalWrite(10, LOW);
                delayMicroseconds(600);
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                delayMicroseconds(300);
            }
            delay(1000);  
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the modified C# code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string n =  tbgoc.Text.ToString();
    string t = cbPORT.Text.ToString();
    serial(t, n+","); //Include a comma as data separator
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I can send my data the way i want. I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day.